# Properties of sum of two metrics

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I try to show that the sum of two metrics is again a metric for the product space $X\times Y$
$$d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=d_X(x_1,y_1)+d_Y(x_2,y_2)$$

I showed the triangle inequality but fail at

1. Showing identity of indiscernibles. I see that this can only be true if $$d_X(x_1,y_1)=d_Y(x_2,y_2)=0$$ because of positivity. But how can I conclude that $(x_1,x_2)=(x_2,y_2)$?

Because $d((1,1),(2,2))=d_X(1,1)+d_Y(2,2)=0$ but obviously $(1,1)\neq (2,2)$

2. I also don't know how to show symmetry. Symmetry must imply that $d_X(x_1,y_1)-d_X(x_2,y_2)=d_Y(x_1,y_1)-d_Y(x_2,y_2)$, but this is only true for $d_X=d_Y$ or?

Comment: I think you have your variables in the wrong order on the right-hand side of your defining equation for the new metric.

Comment: So you mean $$d\left(\left(x_1,y_1\right),\left(x_2,y_2\right)\right) = d_X\left(x_1,x_2\right) + d_Y\left(y_1,y_2\right),$$ right?

Comment: My exercise sheet says actually $d_X(x_1,y_1)+d_Y(x_2,y_2)$ but yes I assume this is wrong and doesn't make sense, since $y_1\in Y$. So no wonder I didn't figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Since $d_X(x_1,x_2)=d_Y(y_1,y_2)=0$, $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$. So, $(x_1,x_2)=(y_1,y_2)$.
- $d_X(x_1,x_2)+d_Y(y_1,y_2)=d_X(x_2,x_1)+d_Y(y_2,y_1)$, since $d_X$ and $d_Y$ are distances.

Comment: Thank you, there is actually a mistake in the equation on my exercise sheet using $d_X(x_1,y_1)$ but I assume this only makes sens when $X=Y$ which would be trivial.